# Tkinter Button with 2 images (ON/OFF) saving variables on exit, load them back in next session

Tags: user-interface, tkinter

I have a simple  button with 2 images to represent its on / off state .

```
def Clickm():
    if Clickm :
        Buttonm.configure(image= photoMicMute)
        pyautogui.hotkey("ctrl", "shift", "m", interval=0.1)
        Clickm=False


    else:
        Buttonm.configure(image= photoMic)
        pyautogui.hotkey("ctrl", "shift", "m", interval=0.1)
        Clickm =True


Buttonm = Button(f1, image=photoMic, command=Clickm)
Buttonm.config(bd=8, relief=RAISED, width=130, height=130)
Buttonm.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=2, pady=2)
```

I want to save that Button state (True/False) on exit.
This way on next startup i can load it back in ,then make the app 'remember' if it was ON or OFF .
I've tried with picke but not entirely sure how to do it.

Comment: You can simply use a text file to save the button state.  So what is the difficulty you come across? Don't know how to read/write text file?

Comment: Just unsure how  to do it properly .
i'm very new to programming.
i know how to read/write but for some reason can't get the value to load back and affect the button state ..
sorry again total noob here.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just save it as a seperate json file or use configparser to store it in an ini file.

If you start the script, you simply load the ini or json file.

json:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

configparser:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html